# Error sending query in GraphQL with vue and apollo

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I have a code in which I need to make a list with different star wars movies, in the query that I have in the following MoviesList.vue file works directly on the following link: https://movie-database-graphql.herokuapp.com/graphiql I do not know if I'm collecting the data wrong or not, but the query works for me in the link. I leave the files:

Error:

```
Error sending the query 'movies' ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-link-http-common/lib/bundle.esm.js:46:25)
```

MoviesList.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <movie-item v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id" :movie="movie"></movie-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MovieItem from "./MovieItem";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const GET_MOVIES = gql`
  query StarWars {
    movies(query: "Star Wars") {
      id
      poster_path
      title
      overview
    }
  }
`;

export default {
  name: "MoviesList",
  components: { MovieItem },
  data() {
    return {
      movies: []
    };
  },
  apollo: {
    movies: {
      query: GET_MOVIES
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

MovieItem.vue:

```
<template>
  <div :key="movie.id">
    <h3>{{ movie.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ movie.overview }}</p>
    <p>{{ movie.poster_path }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MovieItem",
  props: ["movie"]
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the error you are seeing. You can see the full response from the server inside the network tab of your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Hi, @DanielRearden, this is the error: `Error sending the query 'movies' ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-link-http-common/lib/bundle.esm.js:46:25)`

Comment: The server is returning an HTML response instead of JSON, which Apollo can't parse into a response. Usually this means your client configuration is incorrect. You can see additional details by looking at the actual server response.

Comment: @DanielRearden and how can I do that? Should I reinstall apollo?

Comment: Like I said, you can inspect the request and response inside the network tab of your browser's [dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools).